# Virtualenvwrapper can't find virtualenv on Mavericks

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper via pip (globally.) All other python (2.7) packages/binaries/libraries are installed/managed via MacPorts (including pip.)

virtualenv in not on the PATH because pip installs it to '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages'. I get errors when running virtualenvwrapper commands saying that virtualenv can't be found on PATH. But I'm confused why adding this directory to the PATH is not mentioned anywhere (blogs, virtualenv site, virtualenvwrapper site, here) so it feels like I'm missing something. I don't want to add this directory to the path because it feels like it's going to affect my system when I switch python versions depending upon what I'm working on...

So how do I fix this?

There are versions of virtualenv and virtualenv in both pip and MacPorts. The virtualenv site suggests installing virtualenv/-wrapper via pip; however, I assume the MacPorts version(s) would not have this problem.

Comment: ah, found this on virtualenvwrapper site:

"To override the $PATH search, set the variable VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON to the full path of the interpreter to use and VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV to the full path of the virtualenv binary to use. Both variables must be set before sourcing virtualenvwrapper.sh. "

Answer (score 1):

The MacPorts version of virtualenv is in fact select-able between different versions by using e.g.:

```
port select --set virtualenv virtualenv27
```

However, there `select` command does not work for `virtualenvwrapper`, because the group 'virtualenvwrapper' does not exist.